# What part of the root '/' file system for a linux file system can be deleted and replaced?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

For example, what if I deleted all of the contents in the bin folder and then replaced them with the contents of another bin folder, will the system run? If the file system tied down to its own files? Lets say there is an an essential file that has 444 permissions, can I just delete it and create another one of the same exact kind, but with 777 permissions and have it work? For other folder in other operating systems, can I just copy and paste over the folders and it will still boot?

Comment: Note that there is a big difference between deleting the contents of the bin folder, then copying files to it and overwriting the files in /bin. Without some of the programs in /bin your system will not work anymore.

Comment: ChromeOS *is* Linux.

Answer (score 3):

Any files in any (known?) operating system can be replaced.

The critical question is: replaced with what?

There are various reasons why a file might not be compatible with its replacement.  These reasons are too many to list entirely but to give you a flavour:

- Compiled programs and libraries are compiled for a specific CPU architecture.  You cannot (generally) drop in an ARM compiled file on an AMD64 system.
- Command line utilities such as those in `/bin` are often used in scripts (located in `/usr/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin`).  If you replace `/bin` with those from another system and they are both based on the same upstream package then it *might not* cause too many problems.  But if they are wildly different such as one using [GNU Core Utils](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_GNU_Core_Utilities_commands) and the other using [Busybox](https://boxmatrix.info/wiki/BusyBox-Commands) then it's quite likely that they will be incompatible.
- Library versions can also be a problem.  When programs are compiled they are compiled against a specific versions compiled versions of libraries they use.  It's very easy to cause all kinds of memory leaks and "illegal operation" errors by swapping in the wrong version of a library.

---

I've deliberately glossed over the point that if you do something as catastrophic as deleting `/bin` then you will cause your system all kinds of problems until it get's replaced and may leave it non-functional.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple questions:

> what if I deleted all of the contents in the bin folder and then replaced them with the contents of another bin folder, will the system run?

No. If you delete `/bin` you won't have an programs available to replace its contents (`mkdir`, `cp`, `mv`, etc. will all have been deleted).

Even if you saved off those tools, you would also need to ensure that the replacements were built to use the matching versions of libraries you had got on your system.

> Is the file system tied down to its own files? Lets say there is an an essential file that has 444 permissions, can I just delete it and create another one of the same exact kind,

Possibly. But not if you're running something like SELinux in enforcing mode.

> but with 777 permissions and have it work?

Probably not. Permissions are there for a reason. If you change the permissions of certain programs (`sudo`, `passwd`) or files (`/etc/passwd`) you will stop the system operating.

> For other folder in other operating systems, for example chrome OS, you can just copy and paste over the folders and it will still boot.

I wonder if that's because ChromeOS always reinstalls or resets its `/bin` at boot time. I find it hard to believe it would continue to work correctly otherwise.

Comment: *"If you delete /bin you won't have an programs available to replace its contents (mkdir, cp, mv, etc. will all have been deleted)."* `rsync`?  I largely agree with you.  Just playing devils advocate.

Comment: @PhilipCouling `/bin` is often a symlink to `/usr/bin` so `rsync` will also be gone.

Comment: @doneal24 in that case reinstating `/bin` would be `ln -s /usr/bin /bin`, surely

Comment: @doneal24 you are over generalizing.  It depends on which distros you are describing. Archlinux and I guess redhat forks (though I only use Amazon linux under redhat these days).  But Debian and Alpine derivatives don't.

Comment: Depends on if you ran `rm -rf /bin/`. Trailing slash makes a difference.

Comment: @Philip new Debian 11 installations have merged / and /usr by default (*i.e.* symlinks).

Comment: @doneal24 thanks guys for the contributions, I found this -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/906674/accidentally-removed-bin-how-do-i-restore-it  it seems to be helpful.

Comment: V.Villacis were you asking how to fix your system after having accidentally deleted `/bin`? Because that's not what you asked, and there are answers for that separately

Comment: @StephenKitt ah that's a pretty new change then.  Okay I guess it will filter through soon enough.

Comment: @roaima thanks for taking the time to answer. I was asking if the files deleted and are unrecoverable; can they be replaced with similar files from another system. Meaning are the files replaceable and not tied down. In which case the answer in the link provided makes it seem that if those files are gone, they can be replaced. I am just playing around with system files in virtualbox and got curious.

Comment: The question was phrased as "what if" rather than "how do I fix it?". The answers you've got reflect that. If you had explained this is something you had done you would have got practical "this is how you fix it" answers

Answer (score 2):

The only possible answer is: **it depends**.

Files change all the time (for instance when the system is updated or a config is changed). But deleting/replacing files and directories blindly in your system will have unforeseen consequences which may vary from "nothing" to "have your system unable to boot and needing a complete reinstall".

`/bin` and `/sbin` contain important binaries and system commands; messing up them is not recommended. On the other hand, deleting files in `/var/log` will only cause you to lose information about system logs. And deleting anything in an (unprivileged) user home's directory won't affect other users.

The same can be said with changing permissions. Removing the `x` permissions on an executable file will impede it from running. Changing permission from 444 to 777 for most files won't make a noticeable difference at first, except that e.g. you'll be making the file world-writable and hence is a security issue. Also note that some files, such as SSH private keys, need to have a specific, restricted set of permissions.